# How to debug local notifications on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

Is there any way to get a list of scheduled local notifications on Android? I've looked through Android Studio, and while there are loads of useful features, I found nothing that would help me to see a list of scheduled notifications. It would be very convenient to have an "inspector" which lists all local notifications and updates list in real time, while developer is testing application. Now I waste a lot of time by setting up notifications and waiting at least a minute for them to pop up.